# How to get canvas of separate View

Tags: android, canvas, view

I would like to use some custom views in layout like is shown on picture.

[image]

Red rectangle it's just border of view. There are could be different things inside.

For that I created custom View:

public class CustomView extends View {

```
public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawCircle(5, 5, 5, paint);
    canvas.save();
}
```

}

and then somewhere in onCreate() method I add some views to layout:

```java
layout.addView(new CustomView(this));
layout.addView(new CustomView(this));
```

As result circle is drawn on the top left side of layout (black rectangle on the picture).

I thought that onDraw() method containt Canvas of separate view.

How to draw something in scope of separate view but not of all layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in xml. You can create a drawable resource(called red_border.xml)...

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
            <size android:width="25dp" android:height="25dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and assign that to a particular view.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/red_border">
</LinearLayout>
```

This will work for more views than just layouts(TextView, EditText, etc...).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just realized you may have been talking about how to do this using canvas. But this should be able to give you the look that you want.